# How to make yasnippet fall back to self-insertion when it shouldn't expand

Tags: yasnippet

I've decided to try out `yasnippet` recently, and while it seems to work for me, I have an issue with how it handles comments. I've set my trigger key to <kbd>SPC</kbd>, which causes unnecessary snippet expansion in comments (and strings).

It seems that `yasnippet` has a predefined condition to avoid expansion in such cases in `yas-not-string-or-comment-condition`, but it causes the trigger key to do nothing rather than falling back to its original behavior, namely `self-insert-command`. After checking whether setting `yas-buffer-local-condition` to `yas-not-string-or-comment-condition` solves the problem for me, I attempted to wrap the function that's bound to trigger keys (`yas-expand-from-trigger-key`) with advice that falls back to running `self-insert-command`, but that fails since I don't have access to the key that was pressed.

Has anyone ran into this issue (I wasn't able to find any questions about this here, or in github issues for `yasnippet`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

This is the recommended way, but unfortunately it can't work in my Emacs,
I don't know why, but you could try it:

```
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "SPC") yas-maybe-expand)
```

Edit after a few months later: this issue has been fixed, see [this issue](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/973) if you're insterested in.

---

After digging into the source code a bit, I find that below settings could help:

```
(setq yas-buffer-local-condition yas-not-string-or-comment-condition)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "SPC") 'yas-expand)  ; assume you use this
(setq yas-fallback-behavior 'call-other-command)         ; default is 'return-nil
```

But it says `yas-fallback-behavior` is obsolete, and `yas-maybe-expand` should
be used instead, which I haven't figured out how to yet :(

P.S. There is a github [issue](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/808) about this.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. Here's the related commit for my config file: https://github.com/DoMiNeLa10/.emacs.d/commit/891dcf5afdc51cad73842013e494968dec1c2cd1. I'll give you the bounty and accept the question once I'm able to.

Comment: So `yas-maybe-expand` also doesn't work for you? Sounds like a bug then.